# Overwriting the fields of a superclass within a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, final

Lets say I have a superclass `Test1`

```
public class Test1{
  public int foo;

  public void bar(final Integer value){
    foo = 0;
  }
}
```

And the subclass `Test2`

```
public class Test2 extends Test1{

  public void bar(final Integer value){
    foo = value;
  }
}
```

1) What does `final` in the class `Test2` mean? And what does declaring a parameter final do and what would be the purpose?
Does this only mean, that the parameter can not change within the method?

2) If I call the method bar which was overwritten in `Test2`, does it only change the inheritated field `foo` of `Test1` or would this change the the fields in of `Test2` as well as `Test1`?

Comment: See this for #1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306313/final-variable-in-methods-in-java

Comment: If you do `new Test2()` there is only a `Test2` object, no `Test1` object is created.