# Java speed access array index versus temp variable

Tags: java, arrays, performance

What is faster in Java. Accessing an array index directly multiple times, or saving the value of the array index to a new variable and use this for following compution?

**acces index**

```
if ((shape.vertices[0].x >= fromX && shape.vertices[0].x <= toX) || // left side of shape in screen
    (shape.vertices[0].x <= fromX && shape.vertices[0].x + shape.width >= fromX) || // right side of shape in screen
    (shape.vertices[0].x >= fromX && shape.vertices[0].x + shape.width <= toX)) { // shape fully in screen

    // ...
}
```

**temp variable**

```
float x = shape.vertices[0].x;
float y = shape.vertices[0].y;
if ((x >= fromX && x <= toX) || // left side of shape in screen
    (x <= fromX && x + shape.width >= fromX) || // right side of shape in screen
    (x >= fromX && x + shape.width <= toX)) { // shape fully in screen

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: If it really makes a difference, then the JIT will probably optimize these to the same compiled code.  I wouldn't expect there to be a performance difference at all.  Which one is more _readable_ is pretty subjective, though I would lean towards option 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second approach is definitely faster. But you can help even more with the `final` keyword:

```
final float x = shape.vertices[0].x;
final float y = shape.vertices[0].y;
final int rightEdge = x + shape.width;
if ((x >= fromX && x <= toX) || // left side of shape in screen
(x <= fromX && rightEdge >= fromX) || // right side of shape in screen
(x >= fromX && rightEdge <= toX)) { // shape fully in screen

    // ...
}
```

Not a significant improvement of course (but still an improvement and also makes the intent clear). You can read this discussion: http://old.nabble.com/Making-copy-of-a-reference-to-ReentrantLock-tt30730392.html#a30733348

Comment: I doubt that you'll get a measurable difference in performance from the `final` (but then again it's a good idea to use it to make the intent clear).

Comment: how/why does final make it faster?

Comment: I would have though that the JVM would optimise the code this way for you.

Comment: @SteveKuo it may have impact: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316352/why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final-in-java

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky It has no impact. The generated byte code is identical with and without `final`. Try it yourself and see (use `javap -c`).

Comment: @SteveKuo ok, it has no impact. But still doesn't hurt and makes the intent clear (temp. caching of variables for read-only purposes).

Answer (score 2):

In the long run declaring a temp array would be quicker because the jvm has to compute the offset when accessing an array element.

Use a profiling tool and see which is quicker for your use, but I'd caution that unless you're doing something really intensive that is very time-sensitive, this isn't going to be a huge improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code through a profiler to answer the question for your usecase.

The answer to this will probably be JVM specific. The Oracle HotSpot JVM is going to perform differently than OpenJDK or IBM's JDK. Timings will depend on how the JVM optimizes the byte code, what it decides to compile while it is running. Server vs client mode will probably make a difference too.

So aim for readability. Optimize after profiling and determining that section of code is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is faster, but will consume more memory. But the performance increases is only nano seconds, unless you array size is huge.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend second approach, simply because it is a lot more **readable** and helps a lot the **maintainability**.

Performance gains, except if your array is huge, are really really small.

Readability gains, on the other hand, are always good to take.

Comment: @zolex : Well, then I'd go for Chris Blade's answer : Use a profiling tool :)

Answer (score -1):

Array access could be faster. Note the following program:

```
public class ArraySpeedTest{

public static void main(String [] args){

    float x = 4.4f;
    float [] xArr = new float[1];
    xArr[0] = 4.4f;

    long time1 = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000*1000*1000; i++){
        if(x > 1 && x < 5){

        }
    }
    long time2 = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println(time2-time1);

    long time3 = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000*1000*1000; i++){
        if(xArr[0] > 1 && xArr[0] < 5){
        }
    }
    long time4 = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println(time4-time3);


}

}
```

OUTPUT::
5290289
2130667

JVM implementations, flags, and order of the program can change the performance on the order of a few milliseconds.

Comment: Array is only faster because the variable loops are being used for warming up the jvm. Subsequent executions show that var access is definitely faster:   var: 2802110900
arr: 2660019100
var: 2515318700
arr: 2670587900
var: 2487106500
arr: 2682468400
var: 2485047300
arr: 2642655100
var: 2501300200
arr: 2672457400
var: 2495593500
arr: 2650383400
var: 2489377200
arr: 2646188100
var: 2501328200
arr: 2643038700
var: 2489211300
arr: 2641330100
var: 2495374900
arr: 2662683300