# What is the purpose of using final for the loop variable in enhanced for loop?

Tags: java, variables, foreach, final

I understand how the below statement works.

```
for(final Animal animal : animalList){
//do some function
}
```

But what is the purpose of using the final keyword here ?

Comment: It just means that the variable `animal` can't be reassigned e.g. `animal = new Animal(); //inside the loop code`.

Comment: @Luiggi -> Will variable `animal` not be assigned a new reference on each iteration ?

Comment: @LearnMore note the comment: *inside the loop code*.

Comment: @LearnMore The entire variable is redeclared for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for response. Answers by Tala and Kan clarify this more.

Comment: @LearnMore even if you don't mark the `Animal animal` as `final` and reassign it inside the `for` loop, the value stored in the `Collection` won't be modified since it's just a copy. With this as basis, StephenC is right by saying *It could simply be a way to avoid changing the loop variable accidentally* and also provides another reason none of the other answered considered.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two possible reasons to do this:

- It could simply be a way to avoid changing the loop variable accidentally in the loop body.  (Or to *document* the fact that the loop variable is not going to be changed.)
- It could be done so that you can refer to the loop variable in an anonymous inner class.  For example:

  ```
  for(final Animal animal : animalList){
      executor.submit(new Runnable(){
          public void run() {
              animal.feed();
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  It is a compilation error if you leave out the `final` in this example.

  **UPDATE** it is not a compilation error in Java 8 and later versions.  The non-local variable is now only required to be *effectively final*.  In simple terms, that means that the variable is not assigned to (using an assignment operator or a pre/post increment or decrement operator) after the initial declaration / initialization.

Answer (score 10):

Adding `final` keyword makes no performance difference here. It's just needed to be sure it is not reassigned in the loop.

To avoid this situation which can lead to confusions.

```
 for(Animal animal : animalList){
       //do some function
       animal = anotherAnimal;
       // use animal variable here
    }
```

You could also need to use this variable in anonymous function inside the loop

Answer (score 3):

It simply means that the value of `animal` cannot change once it is set by the for loop. This may be required if you're going to reference `animal` within an anonymous class at some point in the loop.

Even if it isn't explicitly needed, it is good practice to make variables that will not change final. It can help you catch mistakes, and makes the code more self-documenting.

Answer (score 2):

It's another java best practise.

The `final` declaration causes `Java` compilers to  reject any  assignments made to the loop `variable`.

When ever you have a chance, [Declare all enhanced for statement loop variables final](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/DCL02-J.+Do+not+modify+the+collection%27s+elements+during+an+enhanced+for+statement)

Comment: I don't find that as a Java best practice at all. If you think or know it is, please add a link that proves it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Where ever we have a chance to  mark a something as `final`  i'l simply go for it.Correct me if i'm wrong :)

Comment: So you think declaring the parameters on setters as `final` is a best practice at all? Also, your link doesn't provide a **real** difference between marking the variable as `final` or not, note that you can use the `continue` keyword in both examples and the behavior will be **the same**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316352/why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final-in-java

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes,I believe in that statement.**where ever you have a chance**

Comment: This is "a good idea" but not "best practice".  Something only qualifies as best practice when *most* practitioners (i.e. most experienced Java developers) would agree that it is the best solution.  IMO, *most* Java developers would NOT agree that you should declare loop variables final "whenever you have the chance".

Comment: Please read [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164) ... and consider removing "best practice" from you vocabulary.

Comment: Also note that misunderstanding `final` is a common pitfall. `final` only locks the content of primitive types or the reference to an object. The referee object state can still mutate.

Answer (score 0):

The code is a syntax sugar for this equivalent code:

```
for (final Iterator<Animal> iterator = animals.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
  final Animal animal = iterator.next();

}
```

I think it is answers the question.

Comment: I don't understand how an `Animal` can easily change to `String`. And no, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry, it was typo. If he knows what final variables mean, then it is easy to understand. BTW, afair this is impossible to do in C# for example.

Comment: I find the answer on the posted Q/A more appropiate.