# Convert a List of objects to a String array

Tags: java

I have the below pojo  which consists of the below members so below is the pojo with few members in it

```
public class TnvoicetNotify  {
    private List<TvNotifyContact> toMap = new ArrayList<TvNotifyContact>();
    private List<TvNotifyContact> ccMap = new ArrayList<TvNotifyContact>();

}
```

now in some other class i am getting the object of above class TnvoicetNotify in a method signature as parameter as shown below ..  So i want to write the code of extraction from list and storing them in string array within this method itself

```
public void InvPostPayNotification(TnvoicetNotify TnvoicetNotify)
    {

        String[] mailTo =  it should contain all the contents of list named toMap  
        String[] mailCC =  it should contain all the contents of list named ccMap 
     }
```

now in the above class i need to extract the toMap which is of type list in the above pojo named TnvoicetNotify and i want to store each item if arraylist in a string array as shown in below fashion

for example first item in list is A1 and second is A2 and third is A3
so it should be stored in string array as

```
 String[] mailTo = {"A1","A2","A3"};
```

similarly i want to achieve the same for cc section also as in above pojo it is in list   i want to store in the below fashion

```
 String[] mailCc = {"C1","C2","C3"};
```

so pls advise how to achieve this within InvPostPayNotification method

Comment: You should post the code for `TvNotifyContact`

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code, because I don't know details for `TnvoicetNotify`:

```
public void invPostPayNotification(final TnvoicetNotify tnvoicetNotify)
{
    final List<String> mailToList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final TvNotifyContact tv : tnvoicetNotify.getToMap()) { // To replace: getToMap() 
        mailToList.add(tv.getEmail()); // To replace: getEmail() 
    }
    final String[] mailTo = mailToList.toArray(new String[mailToList.size()])
    // same for mailCc then use both arrays
}
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, why `final`? And how could it be changed at every iteration?

Comment: I missed 2 ;) Because I'm used to it. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019582/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-final-for-the-loop-variable-in-enhanced-for-loop

Comment: Nice, you're reminding me of Josh Bloch. But won't this interfere in the enhanced loop?

Comment: "But won't this interfere in the enhanced loop" => nope

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you could simply use a one liner :

```
String[] mailCC = ccMap.stream().map(TvNotifyContact::getEmail).toArray(String[]::new);
```