# Using final parameter correctly in Java

Tags: java, c++, final

In C++, as much as I know, it is a good practice to add `const` parameter to these variables which are not going to change and to these methods, which return values, for example:

```
bool ExpenseManager::checkCategory(const string &userName, const string &categName) const{}
```

My question: is it a good practice to use `final` in Java just like `const` in c++ and declare specific methods and/or variables `final` (like for values which are passed for constructor (`public Something(final String haha)`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would one mark local variables and method parameters as "final" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316352/why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that declaring a parameter `final` in Java is an implementation detail while a `const` parameter in C/C++ changes the method signature! `final` only means that the variable will not change. Any object referenced by the variable CAN change. So, `final` means NOTHING for the caller of the method. In contrast a `const` parameter defines a contract with the caller: The method promises that it will not alter any data handed in via the parameter. With java, you cannot create such a contract so you must fall back to immutable objects or defensive copies.

So to get back to your question: Since `final` is an implementation detail, it does not matter when considering interfaces. It is rather a matter of taste. Some people, especially those coming from a functional language love `final`, since they state that a variable should only be mutable when it is actually mutated somewhere. Others simply don't like the added keyword which adds visual noise.

Usually, this decision is made on a project level: Either use `final` everywhere in the project or nowhere. Every developer on the project should do the same thing or the code will look inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

The `final` keyword has different meanings when used on methods and on method parameters.

- When on a method, it means this method cannot be overriden.
- When on a method parameter, it means the method cannot
  change this parameter's value in its body.

**EDIT:**

In some cases, the compiler forces you to declare them final. Here is one such example (this is some typical DAO code). So people usually do it only when the compiler forces them to do it.

```
public List<Process> getProcesses(final Integer uid, final String status) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) 
                throws HibernateException, SQLException 
        {
            StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder
            ("select * from [process] where [uid] = :u and [status] = :s");

            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sbQuery.toString());

            query.addEntity(Process.class);

            query.setParameter("u", uid);
            query.setParameter("s", status);

            List l = query.list();
            return (List<Process>)l;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, that I understand. Its just that I have never seen a piece of code, where passed variables would be declared as final in method (even though they never change).

Comment: @user3178137 I'm not sure what the semantics in C++ are, but I'd just like to add that in Java, `final` on reference variables just means you can't reassign the variable. You're still free to change the object that the variable refers to. In addition, `final` on static methods means that you can't hide the method, because static methods can't be overridden in the first place.

Comment: @user3178137 Added one example and some additional notes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. The Eclipse IDE has code clean up settings that will do this for you automatically, although I only use it for method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful while using `final` keyword in java

1.Applying `final` keyword to variables in which we cannot reassign the value to thet variable

2.If a method decared as `final` that method cannot overridden

3.If class declared as `final` that cannot be extends(key benifit of inheritance will be lossed)

```
   What i can say is Think before using `final` keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a method parameter as final has the following implications :

- The method **cannot** change the method parameter to point to another reference.
- The method **CAN** modify the method parameter i.e change the state of the object being referred by the parameter (modify instance variables)

I will illustrate this with the following example. Assume I have a Class to represent an employee :

```
class Employee
{
    public String name;
    public Integer id;
}
```

Case 1 :

```
  public void test(final Employee emp)
  {
       emp = new Employee(); //Invalid since you are changing the reference
  }
```

**Case 2 :**

```
   public void test(final Employee emp)
   {
       emp.name = "John Doe"; //Valid
   }
```

This is different from a const parameter in C++ which also stops the method from making any changes to the state of the object/reference being passed.