# How can I sort a Map according to the parameters of its values?

Tags: java, java-8

```
Stream<Map.Entry<String, List<Object>>> sorted = index.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

> The method `sorted(Comparator<? super Map.Entry<String,List<NFArticle>>>)` in the type `Stream<Map.Entry<String,List<NFArticle>>>` is not applicable for the 
>            arguments `(Comparator <Map.Entry<Object,Comparable<? super Comparable<? super V>>>>)`

I want to sort a `Hashmap` according to the `size()` of Lists being the values of the `HashMap`. How can I achieve this using the Stream library from Java 8?

Comment: I copied the code from that post, but I don't know how to access the size() parameter of the List values in this case since comparingByValue seems to work on primitive data types and Strings only(?)

Comment: Are you trying to sort map entries by size of lists (which are entry's value)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be helpful to you.

I changed the type of result map to *LinkedHashMap* to respect insertion order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("k1", Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
    map.put("k2", Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}));
    map.put("k3", Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));
    System.out.println(getMapSortedByListSize(map));
}

public static <K, V> Map<K, List<V>> getMapSortedByListSize(final Map<K, List<V>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().size() - e2.getValue().size())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: @AlexisC. What do u mean?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));` could be writed as `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: * could be written (dear my english)

Comment: why is the parameter of the method declared final?

Comment: @Pete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316352/why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final-in-java

Comment: @AlexisC. I didn't know about this option. Thanks! It was a first thing I learned today.

Answer (score 3):

`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` will only work if the values in the map are `Comparable`, and `List` is not `Comparable`. The error from the compiler is telling you that.

You need to provide a custom `Comparator` which knows how to sort lists by their size, e.g.

```
Map.Entry.comparingByValue((list1, list2) -> list1.size() - list2.size())
```

Comment: ... or `comparingByValue(comparingInt(List::size))` (with static imports)

Answer (score 0):

`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` cannot serve as the comparator.

This is a comparator for `Stream<T> sorted(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`:

```
Stream<Entry<String, List<Object>>> sortedStream = index.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,List<Object>>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, List<Object>> o1, Entry<String, List<Object>> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().size()-o2.getValue().size();
    }
});
```

Comment: `Map.Entry.comparingByValue() ` can serve as a comparator if the values of the map are comparable. This is not the case for List and hence the compile error. If not you can just provide one to the overloaded method (and it avoids to provide a comparator for the entries instead since you are interested to compare the entries only with their respective values)... Furthermore, your code could be simplified with lambda expressions here