# Intellij Idea propose to set final for everything if possible, why?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, final

I'm a bit confused, my Intellij Idea warns me if no final modifiers everywhere when possible.

Actually final is very good option, and of course its needed in lots of cases like methods parameters, constants and ... ,

But ...

Probably there are some really strong arguments why my local method variables should be final ?

Could you pls help me understand a benefit of such mass **final**  usage ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316352/why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final-in-java

Comment: one more thing im thinking, in my undertanding final previously had some "special meaning", it even has a sense to describe some API specifics etc... Now looking at final everywhere, i think this sense is kind of lost.

Comment: IMHO, making parameters and local variables final just adds a whole lot of noise in the code, making it more verbose and harder to read, without any real advantage.

Comment: Making local variables `final` helps you reason about variables because you know the value is never assigned; but there is a school of thought that if you *really* need to do that for reasoning purposes, your method is probably too big anyway.

Comment: Some people just make a superstition out of best practices. "Immutable is good, so `final` everywhere must be better." The idea is that code maintainers will save time not worrying about whether a variable's been reassigned. IntelliJ apparently bought into this idea. I am not aware of any _evidence_ that `final` everywhere provides a net benefit, but I haven't seen any harm from it. I personally like to put `final` on local variables that are otherwise "effectively final", but I admit to being superstitious there.

Comment: I'll bet you can turn this off if you prefer.  My IntelliJ does no such thing for me.  Check out the global settings.

Answer (score 3):

A benefit of making all variables final is that it is clearly visible which variables are assigned only once. Another is that it is possible to use such a variable in an anonymous class without having to make it final (because it already final but this benefit has disappeared with Java 8).

Both of the benefits above are not very strong, so perhaps you just want to disable the *Local variable or parameter can be final* inspection. This inspection is disabled by default, so you may have enabled it by accident?