# Should I mark all method parameters as final and specify type

Tags: flutter, dart

Effective dart specifies that top-level variables should be `final` when applicable:
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_final_fields.html

However, I could not find any information about method parameters.

Flutter repo's code functions are mostly ones with parameters not marked `final`, that includes all the overridden `build` methods I've seen.

Which of the following is better in terms of performance and app weight:

`@override build(context)`

`@override build(BuildContext context)`

`@override build(final BuildContext context)`

Perhaps overridden functions should be defined the same way as the super function? Is there any difference between overridden functions like `build` above which can infer the type, and other named/unnamed functions (other than not setting the type makes the variable dynamic), which Flutter repo also writes this way:

```
static double _flingDistancePenetration(double t) { // t is not final, although treated as immutable
 return (1.2 * t * t * t) - (3.27 * t * t) + (_initialVelocityPenetration * t);
}
```

I've seen this question about Java: [Why would one mark local variables and method parameters as "final" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316352/why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final-in-java), and, while I agree with the top answer, I'm completely in the dark about why does Flutter repo not do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding parameter types: yes, always include them.  Otherwise your parameter is likely to be `dynamic`<sup>1</sup>, which incurs runtime overhead and no type safety.  You also want your API to clearly specify what argument types it expects.

Regarding `final`: That is an opinion-based question, and my opinion is that while I agree with the `prefer_final_fields` lint, I disagree with the `prefer_final_locals` lint.  I think that adding `final` for local variables (including function/method parameters) is pointless.

- Contrary to what the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/316787/) to the related Java question says, any half-decent compiler should be able to easily determine whether a local variable is reassigned.  If there's any optimization opportunity there, the compiler should be able to do it for you.
- In languages such as Dart where implementation usually is inline with the interface (as opposed to languages such as C or C++, which have separate header files to declare interfaces), adding `final` to parameters is visual noise.  It provides no useful information to callers.
- You shouldn't unilaterally mark all function/method parameters as `final` anyway.  Sometimes reassigning parameters is appropriate.  For example, if your function needs to perform some sort of normalization on its arguments:

  ```dart
  void foo(File file) {
    file = file.absolute;
    ...
  }
  ```

  in such a case, using a `final File file` would mean you'd need a separate local variable for the normalized version, and now the code would be error-prone since it could accidentally use the original variable.
- `final` for a field is an important part of an API.  It tells callers that the field will not be reassigned; the object referred to by the field will always be the same object. `final` for local variables and for function/method parameters affects only the person implementing the function.  If the implementor doesn't want to reassign a variable, they can choose to simply not reassign it.
- Some people will claim that having `final` local variables helps code readability since they know that the variable will not be reassigned.  However, I instead think that `final` can be misleading since it says only that a variable cannot be reassigned, *not* that it won't be mutated, and knowing the latter is much more important.

---

<sup>1</sup> For overridden methods, parameter types are constrained by the corresponding parameter types declared by the base class.  Therefore omitting a parameter type in an overridden method will use the parameter type from the base class.

Comment: I disagree about `prefer_final_locals`. What's wrong with declaring a local variable as immutable? Only a small part of the local variables are reassigned, most are unchanged (the value is assigned only once). What's the point in declaring them as mutable?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Your points on readability and clarity opened my eyes to a couple of things and provided some read material for probably a week. But I still have a stupid question left unanswered - what about - and I know it's not the first priority for many if not all programmers - performance and compiled file size? Let me put it this way - is there any possible scenario when putting `final` everywhere applicable (except, for example, when the function should normalize the arguments) may do the opposite of optimization? All else equal, putting aside developer's mistakes.

Comment: @AlexeySubbotin That's covered by my first point: marking a local variable `final` (or not) tells the compiler nothing that it couldn't already deduce on its own, so it shouldn't affect optimization opportunities (regardless of whether you choose to optimize for performance or to optimize for size).

Comment: @mezoni `final` does not declare local variables as immutable, but readers might incorrectly believe that it does.  Like I said, it's opinion.  I admit that my argument against `final` for non-parameter local variables is weak, but I think that arguments in favor of it are similarly weak. `final` for local variables doesn't convey intent: it usually represents something that *happens* to be true about the code, not an expected invariant.  Even if the author intends to use `final` to indicate (but not enforce) that a variable should be immutable, there's no way for readers to tell.

Comment: Ha-ha-ha.  From Dart specification: https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf START OF QUOTE
A final variable is a variable whose binding is fixed upon initialization; a 
final variable v will always refer to the same object after v has been initialized.
A variable is final iff its declaration includes the modifier final or the modifier
const. A `mutable` variable is a variable which is `not final`. END OF QUOTE

Comment: @mezoni My mistake.  You are correct: the Dart language specification does define "mutable variable" that way.  I was being imprecise with my language: I meant that `final` does not make the *object* immutable, which is a far more important and interesting distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the author of the question.

1. You should not mark all method parameters as final
2. You should specify the type

Examples:

`foo(Baz baz)`

`void main(List<String> args)`

An exception to these rules.

1. You can omit the type indication if the type is `dynamic`
2. You can don't specify type if the type can be inferred automatically by the compiler, in the case of using an function-expression.

`foo(Baz baz, bar)`

`list.sort((x, y) => x.compareTo(y))`

Some useful information:

From Dart specification:
[Dart Programming Language Specification
5th edition draft
Version 2.2](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf)

A `final variable` is a variable whose binding is fixed upon initialization; a `final` variable `v` will always `refer` to the `same object` after `v` has been initialized. A variable is `final` iff its declaration includes the modifier `final` or the modifier `const`. A `mutable` variable is a variable which is not `final`.

`Variable immutability` does not make an `object immutable` in Dart.

This is a very common misconception when `variable immutability` is confused with `object immutability`.

P.S.

A common misconception is that Dart users get the impression that function parameters in Dart are passed by reference.
This is not true.
Parameters are passed by value (not by reference).
But due to the fact that (as indicated in the specification) any variable already contains a reference (refers) to the object (but not the object itself), in fact, this reference is passed, by value (as normal value).
That is, a value is passed, but the value itself is of the `Referernce` type, which is indicated in the language specification.

From Dart specification:

`a final variable v will always refer to the same object`

That is, the variable stores the `reference`, but not the `value` itself.
It is this `reference` that is `passed by value`, because there is no reason to pass this `reference` by reference.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the distinction between value and reference in method params. Language specs is, imo, too much to read for a user, not a contributor, though. Hope I will get enough time to go through several pages. Thanks for the material.