# Why bother with final if the value can be changed anyway at run time in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart)

The value of variables marked final can be changed at run time, so why bother marking them final anyway?

What would be the difference between:-

```
String x;  
final y;
```

Both can be changed at run time, so why use the final keyword?

Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The `Const` keyword in Dart behaves exactly like the `final` keyword. The only difference between `final` and `const` is that the const makes the variable constant from compile-time only. Using `const` on an object, makes the object’s entire deep state strictly fixed at compile-time and that the object with this state will be considered frozen and completely immutable.

Where as `final` keyword will fix the value in run time.
We cannot change the value of both `final` and `const` variable if once defined.

Comment: `final` does not create a runtime constant.  If a variable named `x` is declared final, that doesn't affect whether the object that `x` refers to is mutable.  It only affects whether `x` can be reassigned to refer to another object.

Answer (score 0):

`const` objects must be immutable, and that requires that its members cannot be reassigned.  Therefore for a class to have a `const` constructor, all of its members must be `final`. `final` is a prerequisite for `const` objects.

Even if a class doesn't have a `const` constructor, it might still want properties that cannot be reassigned as part of its contract.  That either can be done by providing getters without setters, or more succinctly, by providing `final` members.

For local variables, [there is little reason to use `final`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302620/).