# Runnable with a parameter?

Tags: java, runnable

I have a need for a "Runnable that accepts a parameter" although I know that such runnable doesn't really exist.

This may point to fundamental flaw in the design of my app and/or a mental block in my tired brain, so I am hoping to find here some advice on how to accomplish something like the following, *without* violating fundamental OO principles:

```
  private Runnable mOneShotTask = new Runnable(String str) {
    public void run(String str) {
       someFunc(str);
    }
  };
```

Any idea how to accomplish something like the above?

Comment: Now you can use `Consumer<T>`.

Comment: I've read the various answers to this question. It seems me strange that nobody told that you can add to your project the Runnables that you need (with one, two, three or more args) simply adding an appropriate interface. I created a commented gist here for who is interested: https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/3a66e711fd0fd233c5e4c467184adb7a

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate to "How can I pass a parameter to a Java thread". And the modern answer is, like @Alex78191 says: use `Consumer<T>`

Comment: I usually create a class that implements run() and pass what ever data I need into the constructor or accesser/setter.

Comment: @Alex78191, can you further elaborate what you mean by use Consumer<T>?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X https://stackoverflow.com/a/59660705/4854931

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Well it's been almost 9 years since I originally posted this and to be honest, Java has made a couple improvements since then. I'll leave my original answer below, but there's no need for people to do what is in it. 9 years ago, during code review I would have questioned why they did it and maybe approved it, maybe not. With modern lambdas available, it's irresponsible to have such a highly voted answer recommending an antiquated approach (that, in all fairness, was dubious to begin with...) In modern Java, that code review would be immediately rejected, and this would be suggested:

```
void foo(final String str) {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> someFunc(str));
    t.start();
}
```

As before, details like handling that thread in a meaningful way is left as an exercise to the reader. But to put it bluntly, if you're afraid of using lambdas, you should be even more afraid of multi-threaded systems.

Original answer, just because:

You can declare a class right in the method

```
void Foo(String str) {
    class OneShotTask implements Runnable {
        String str;
        OneShotTask(String s) { str = s; }
        public void run() {
            someFunc(str);
        }
    }
    Thread t = new Thread(new OneShotTask(str));
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you all! All of the suggested solution point to the same approach but I can only accept one. I must be very tired not being able to come up with this myself. +1 to all.

Comment: Actually, most people don't know you can declare a class inside a method. Some would consider it to be poor style. I guess it's a matter of taste. :)

Comment: public interface ResultRunnable<T> {
    public void run(T result);
}

Comment: I don't get the more modern approach. OK, there is no `Runnable` anymore. Any change to use it in a `Scheduler`? E.g. `Scheduling scheduling = new Scheduling(1); scheduling.startScheduler(new MyRunnable(), TimeUnit.DAYS, 1);`

Answer (score 52):

You could put it in a function.

```
String paramStr = "a parameter";
Runnable myRunnable = createRunnable(paramStr);

private Runnable createRunnable(final String paramStr){

    Runnable aRunnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            someFunc(paramStr);
        }
    };

    return aRunnable;

}
```

(When I used this, my parameter was an integer ID, which I used to make a hashmap of ID --> myRunnables. That way, I can use the hashmap to post/remove different myRunnable objects in a handler.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code - I love when people do that instead of just blabbering. One question - is above approach OK when it comes to Memory Leaking? All references you pass will be properly disposed of?

Comment: @kape123 The answer is "it depends". As long as a `Runnable` object returned by the method exists anywhere, the `paramStr` will probably not be eligible for garbage collection. It is possible that if the object exists but can never be run again, the JIT (or even javac) may decide to remove it from scope, but we should not rely on such optimizations because they may change in the future.

Answer (score 35):

```
theView.post(new Runnable() {
    String str;
    @Override                            
    public void run() {
        par.Log(str);                              
    }
    public Runnable init(String pstr) {
        this.str=pstr;
        return(this);
    }
}.init(str));
```

Create init function that returns object itself and initialize parameters with it.

Comment: Unfortunately you will not be able to assign it to a variable and call init()

Answer (score 24):

Since Java 8, the best answer is to use `Consumer<T>`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html

It's one of the functional interfaces, which means you can call it as a lambda expression:

```
void doSomething(Consumer<String> something) {
    something.accept("hello!");
}

...

doSomething( (something) -> System.out.println(something) )

...
```

Comment: If still using Runnable with lambda in Java 8, we can do as below:
`void doSomething(String param) { CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> howToDo(param));} private void howToDo(String param) { System.out.println(param);}`

Comment: To support Android API 23 and earlier, there is a compat version in androidx.core: `androidx.core.util.Consumer`

Answer (score 12):

I use the following class which implements the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface.  With this class you can easily create new threads with arguments

```
public abstract class RunnableArg implements Runnable {

    Object[] m_args;

    public RunnableArg() {
    }

    public void run(Object... args) {
        setArgs(args);
        run();
    }

    public void setArgs(Object... args) {
        m_args = args;
    }

    public int getArgCount() {
        return m_args == null ? 0 : m_args.length;
    }

    public Object[] getArgs() {
        return m_args;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you use this abstract class to run a runnable with a parameter?

Comment: I prefer to use constructor with parameter(s) 
`public RunnableArg(Object... args) { 
setArgs(args); 
}`  
then describe local class: 
`class ActionArg extends RunnableArg { public ActionArg(Object... arg) { super(arg); } @Override public void run() { /* getArgs() and process them */ } }` 
and use it 
`Thread t = new Thread(new ActionArg( %param_object(s)% )); t.start();`

Comment: Perfect solution if you're developing for API < 24! I chose this solution over the Consumer<T> solution, which is only for Java 8 (API >= 24). Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You have two options:

1. Define a named class.  Pass your parameter to the constructor of the named class.
2. Have your anonymous class close over your "parameter".  Be sure to mark it as `final`.

Comment: @Massa: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266806/is-there-any-performance-reason-to-declare-method-parameters-final-in-java

Answer (score 5):

I would first want to know what you are trying to accomplish here to need an argument to be passed to new Runnable() or to run().
The usual way should be to have a Runnable object which passes data(str) to its threads by setting member variables before starting. The run() method then uses these member variable values to do execute someFunc()

Answer (score 2):

Best way so far:

```
Consumer<String> oneShot = str -> {
    
   somefunc(str);
    
};

oneShot.accept("myString");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @author AbdelWadoud Rasmi
 * <p>
 * The goal of this class is to pass some parameters to a runnable instance, a good example is
 * after caching a file you need to pass the new path to user to do some work on it.
 */
public abstract class ParameterizedRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Object[] params;

    /**
     * @param params: parameters you want to pass the the runnable.
     */
    public ParameterizedRunnable(Object... params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    /**
     * Code you want to run
     *
     * @param params:parameters you want to pass the the runnable.
     */
    protected abstract void run(Object... params);

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        run(params);
    }

    /**
     * setting params
     */
    public void setParams(Object... params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    /**
     * getting params
     */
    public Object[] getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: This way is the most practical and the easiest way to do that, you only need to create a class inheriting Runnable with parameters (getters/setters) and an other run method, the original overridden run method calls the method u defined (method holding your parameters)

Comment: Nice and clean.

Comment: You're welcome i hope i could help even a bit

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that implements Runnable. In this class you can extend the run() method by making abstract methods of your choice.

```
public abstract class CCallback implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {}

public abstract void run(Object any);

}
```

Now you can use this class as a callback function like this:

```
public void whatever(CCallback callback) {
    String any = "any type of param";
    if (callback != null)
        callback.run(any);
}
```

"Whatever" method can now finish its task before our runnable runs:

```
whatever(new CCallback() {
    @Override
    public void run(Object any) {
        // Here you can reach "any"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the constraints allow it, you can simply do this.

Method.java

```
public interface Method {
    void run(String msg);
}
```

Usage:

```
private Method mOneShotTask = (str) -> someFunc(str);
```