# Swing Runnable with parameters

Tags: java, swing, runnable, event-dispatch-thread, invokelater

I would like to run new Swing thread and pass a parameter into them.
Something like this:

```
String str;

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    Play game = new Play(this.str);
        game.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

I found [answer, how to pass a parameter into thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853167/runnable-with-a-parameter), but I am not sure how to rebuild it for my need.
Thanks for ideas.

Comment: You could use SwingWorker or create a custom class that implements Runnable and takes the parameters you want to pass it

Comment: This is my first graphic java application and it is very simple. @trashgod idea works, so I will not rebuild my code, but I will think at your notice next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, your anonymous `Runnable` can access *final* fields in the enclosing scope:

```
final String str = "one";

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Play game = new Play(str);
        game.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. For reference, see also [*Defining and Starting a Thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Make a new [Thead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) instead.

Edit: Here's some code since you're confused.

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MyThread("StackOverflow"));
  }

  private static class MyThread extends Thread {
    String text;

    public MyThread(String text) {
      this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.println(this.text);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I did not try your code, but thanks for help ;)

Comment: More [commonly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html), `MyRunnable implements Runnable`.