# Android studio app crashing when going to second activity

Tags: android

I"m working on my application, where a user enters a ip address and port number and will connect to the server. As soon as I fill in the ip address and port number and press on connect, the application crashes. These are the errors i'm getting. 
EDIT: added xml for both activities
EDIT2: Changed the textview ID and it's still crashing, new error message all the way down.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.jobush50.irobot, PID: 2285
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jobush50.irobot/com.example.jobush50.irobot.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x22b8
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x22b8
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4550)
                  at com.example.jobush50.irobot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

My MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static int port;
static String ip;

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = port;
private static final String SERVER_IP = ip;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("ip");
    int number = intent.getIntExtra("port", 0);
    port = number;
    ip = name;


    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(name);

    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setText(number);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

SecondActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_port);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_port);
    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            String name = editText.getText().toString();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString() );

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ip", name);
            intent.putExtra("port", number);

            startActivity(intent);


        }



    });
}






}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jobush50.irobot.MainActivity"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Input" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Send"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp">
</Button>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="223dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />
```

activity_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_second"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jobush50.irobot.SecondActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Enter ip address"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText_ip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Connect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="Enter port number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText_port" />
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.jobush50.irobot, PID: 2278
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jobush50.irobot/com.example.jobush50.irobot.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x22b8
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x22b8
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4550)
                  at com.example.jobush50.irobot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Could you please post the contents of `activity_main` and `activity_second `? Looks like there's a problem with resource naming/referencing.

Comment: @thomaspsk I have added the xml code for both activities

Comment: You are referencing `R.id.editText_port` twice in `SecondActivity`... you probably want to use `R.id.editText_ip`....

Comment: @user0815 I changed it and unfortunately it still crashes :(

Comment: You probably need to start your Thread after you've read the intent data...

Comment: @user0815 I placed the start thread code after the intent data and still crashing.

Comment: You need to use `view.findViewByID` in `onClick` in `MainActivity`....

Comment: @user0815 I changed it to view.findViewById(R.id.EditText01); but still not working.

Comment: is it at least a new error? and you might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853198/3104906) to get rid of those static variables like serveraddres and port and pass them as parameters...

Comment: @user0815 Yeah new errors, I have added them all the way down.

Comment: no **new** errors... the same error all the time...

Comment: `textView2.setText(number);` is the problem @user0815, not the threads

Comment: You are right... didn't notice that... but the thread would be a problem too - since he was starting it before he read the correct ip and port...

Comment: @cricket_007 textView2.setText(number); was indeed my problem. It's working now, thank you'll for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textView2.setText(number);
```

The OS is trying to find  match id  since number is int try

```
textView2.setText(String.valueOf(number));
```