# how does it matter for methods to have 'final' parameters in Java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, final

I see some codes that have `method implementation` as

```
public void setVariables(final int value){
this.value=value;
}
```

why is the `final` keyword used in the parameter. 
why not declare

```
public void setVariables(int value){
this.value=value;
}
```

I understand that for `classes` defined inside `methods` that access `method parameters`, they have to declared `final`

what exactly is the benefit of having `final` keyword in `parameter` ?

Comment: What does `final` do when applied to variables? That's your answer.

Comment: I think the question here really is "why do people mark the argument as final when it clearly isn't needed?" and the answer might be "that's just what their IDE template for setters generated"

Comment: Some people use `final` because most of the time a method's parameter value should not be changed inside the method, and `final` enforces that. Other people believe that including `final` on every method parameter introduces unnecessary clutter.

Comment: I think that it is bad idea to pass a constant. It should be public and visible almost to all related classes. If you want to restrict to change variable - simply restrict setters access that's it. In other hand, I mostly use final then I am using anonymous classes and try to pass a variable inside this class method. :)

Comment: @solvator there's no such thing as "passing a constant" in Java; this doesn't do what you think; it's not like `const` in c++ where it says you aren't going to mutate an object. It simply prevents assigning a new value (primitive or reference value) to the variable inside the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the difference is between

```
public int doThing( int value )
{
     value = value*2; // OK
     return value;
}
```

and

```
public int doThing( final int value )
{
     value = value*2; // Not OK
     return value;
}
```

This can be helpful to you as a programmer to prevent you from changing the value accidentally.

**There is one situation where the `final` keyword is necessary**, and that is if you want to use the value in anonymous nested classes, e.g:

```
public Object makeThing( final String name )
{
    return new Object()
        {
            @Override
            public String toString(){
                return name; // Won't work if `name` is not `final`.
            }
        };
}
```

Related:

- [Is there any performance reason to declare method parameters final in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266806/is-there-any-performance-reason-to-declare-method-parameters-final-in-java)
- [When should one use final for method parameters and local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154314/when-should-one-use-final)
- [Using "final" modifier whenever applicable in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java)
- [Why would one mark local variables and method parameters as "final" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316352/why-would-one-mark-local-variables-and-method-parameters-as-final-in-java?rq=1)
- [Why should I use the keyword "final" on a method parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500508/why-should-i-use-the-keyword-final-on-a-method-parameter-in-java?rq=1)

Comment: +1, moreover if you pass a reference, you make it unmodifiable I believe

Comment: @poitevinpm Using `final` on a reference doesn't prevent using the reference to modify the object to which it points.

Comment: @poitevinpm If you pass a reference, you make it impossible to reassign it to another object, but if the object is mutable, you can still change it (e.g. if it is a list, you can still add elements to it).

Comment: This is the correct answer but you have `void` method returning an `int` in your example (just to pick nits).

Comment: I should have known that this is a super-duplicate before answering :/

Comment: actually, there are no examples provided in the duplicate link, I probably got the message faster here than reading that.

Answer (score 1):

to make sure that you don't override that argument

for example to avoid something like this

```
public void setVariables(final int value){
  value = 1;
}
```

Comment: what does that mean? plz give me an example where having the  `final` absolutely essential